# Hide Custom Cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following implementation, where I am adding a footerview as a customcell. However, if there is no content, I do not want to show the last cell, if there is I want to show it.

In my current implementation, it always displays the last cell.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.adminOrderElements count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return adminOrderElements[section].products.count + 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].products.count)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSArray * tempArray = adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].products;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"productname"];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FooterCell";
        FooterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[FooterTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].expanded && [adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].notes length]>0)
        {
            cell.footerLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Notes: %@", adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].notes];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.heightConstraints.constant = 1;
            cell.footerLabel.text = @"";
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one option that you can make cellHeight to 0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(CHECK_IF_NO_CONTAIN)
    return 0;

return 40;// Normal height as you want

}
```

Comment: how do you check for custom cell?

Comment: You just have to implement this method.

Comment: Also need to put condition if you don't get content for particular array index, then you can make height to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add condition in else clause like if certain condition is met then you want to display this cell other wise not...

```
if (indexPath.row < adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].products.count)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        NSArray * tempArray = adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].products;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"productname"];
        return cell;
    }
    else //Here add your condition here if you have content for the section like I think this condition might work [adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].notes length]>0
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FooterCell";
        FooterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[FooterTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].expanded && [adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].notes length]>0)
        {
            cell.footerLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Notes: %@", adminOrderElements[indexPath.section].notes];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.heightConstraints.constant = 1;
            cell.footerLabel.text = @"";
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple with `UITableView` delegate

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (dataObjects.count == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return dataObjects.count;
}
```